# TAR with --to-command

Tags: tar

I'd like to calculate MD5 for all files in a tar archive. I tried tar with --to-command.
`tar -xf abc.tar --to-command='md5sum'` 
it outputs like below.
`cb6bf052c851c1c30801ef27c9af1968  -`
`f509549ab4eeaa84774a4af0231cccae  -`
Then I want to replace '-' with file name.
`tar -xf abc.tar --to-command='md5sum | sed "s#-#$TAR_FILENAME#"'` 
it reports error.
`md5sum: |: No such file or directory
md5sum: sed: No such file or directory
md5sum: s#-#./bin/busybox#: No such file or directory
tar: 23255: Child returned status 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a shell so this won't work (you also might see that the `|` gets to md5sum as an argument). one way could be to invoke the shell yourself, but there is some hassle with nested quotes:

```
tar xf some.tar --to-command 'sh -c "md5sum | sed \"s|-|\$TAR_FILENAME|\""'
```

Answer (score 3):

At first, it's better to avoid using `sed`, not only because it's slow, but because `$TAR_FILENAME` can contain magic chars to be interpreted by sed (you already noticed that, having to use `#` instead of `/` for substitution command, didnt you?). Use deadproof solution, like `head`, followed by echoing actual filename.

Then, as Patrick mentions in his answer, you can't use complex commands without having them wrapped with shell, but for convenience I suggest to use built-it shell escapement ability, for bash it's `printf '%q' "something"`, so the final command be like:

```
tar xf some.tar \
    --to-command="sh -c $(printf '%q' 'md5sum | head -c 34 && printf "%s\n" "$TAR_FILENAME"')"
```

"34" is number of bytes before file name in md5sum output format; `&&` instead of `;` to allow md5sum's error code (if any) reach `tar`; `printf` instead of `echo` used because filenames with leading "-" may be interpreted by `echo` as options.

Comment: I came back here and looked at this answer again (3 years later). I gave you an upvote back then, because I thought it actually was the better answer… With a different view on things (and the world having changed, too), I would have liked to remove it, but SO wouldn't let me, so have a comment: The problem with your answer: `bash`. Less people are using bash today. `printf "%q"` is a bashism (≠ POSIX shell). OP did not contain bash, devs are switching away from bash and containers (where `ash` and `dash` are common): those are reasons I wouldn't promote bashims nowadays (And `sh ≠ bash` today)

Comment: Well. Hello again :) It worth nothing to use coreutils' `printf`: as of 2015-11-04 it is capable to handle %q, escaping non-printable characters with the proposed POSIX syntax (see https://fossies.org/linux/coreutils/ChangeLog). So if one is concerned on portability, it's a good idea to engage `printf` binary instead of shell builtin, just be sure to use `env printf` instead of `/usr/bin/printf`. Aww, dat is ultimately crossshell-proof. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: cool thanks I did not know that! Stil the problem of getting `printf` into apline containers…

Comment: ...In fact for this problem `%q` is not needed. Having things being rechecked yesterday I found out that `sh -c` part may be omitted, i.e. it seems that the `--to-command` already invokes `sh -c` under the hood (I don't remember if it was so 3 years ago, maybe did miss that). So it becomes just `tar xf some.tar --to-command='md5sum | head -c 34 && printf "%s\n" "$TAR_FILENAME"'`. Although `printf` is still needed, because filename may start with `-`. The quite more fun thing is that alpine busybox's tar does not support `--to-command`, you have to `apk add tar` for that to work.

Comment: regarding the `sh -c`: hmm but that was exactly the question (note the error message, tar obviously did not expand the pipe, but gave `|` as an argument to `md5sum`) (but who cares what worked 3 years ago, or not)

Comment: @AlexOffshore, it very much does not appear to me that `sh -c` is implicit. The official docs at https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/external.html specify only shell-like word-splitting; md5sum treating `|` as an argument as shown in the question is consistent with that -- shell-like word-splitting, but no implementation of higher-level features like pipes.